# Prevent folder deletion but allow file deletion in SharePoint Document Library

Tags: folder

Is it possible to only allow file deletion but restrict from Folder deletion?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your requirement by creating an **Event receiver** on `Item Deleting` event to check if the current item is `Folder` or not as the following

```
 public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {

            //if (isFolder)
            if (properties.ListItem.Folder!=null)
            {
                properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelNoError;
                properties.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Any OOTB solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no OOTB solution expect Managing permission that is not a practical solution for large number of folders and files :(